# INSERT INTO syntax seems correct but still fails

Tags: java, mysql, syntax, jax-ws, insert-into

can someone help me out quick, I've been sitting with this for an hour since this post.

Notes: (null) is a string, not actually a NULL value... Should essentially be the same as using 'Hello' as the value

```
INSERT INTO tasks (category,completion_dtm,desc,duedate,notification_duedate,notification_one,notification_two,priority,reminder_one,reminder_two,title,timestamp) VALUES('None','3999-01-01 00:00:00','(null)',('1000-01-01 00:00:00'),'(null)','(null)','(null)',2,('1000-01-01 00:00:00'),('1000-01-01 00:00:00'),'Task 3',('1000-01-01 00:00:00')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id)
```

Is there anything wrong with my syntax? Thanks for any insight!

EDIT:
Sorry, thought the error was obvious enough:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,duedate,notification_duedate,notification_one,notification_two,priority,rem' at line 1
```

Comment: What is the error given?

Comment: What SQL error(s) do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the `desc` being a keyword, it is also worth checking the values you specified on the dates. I believe you have exceeded the limit of the date allowed or less than the minimum date allowed. Check first if the statement will succeed with dates being the current date.

Comment: I will rename all my "desc" uses to something else and will Mark your answer as correct if it was the problem. Else I will change the smaller date to something like 1760 (I think maybe the minimum is 1753 or close to that)

Comment: The desc keyword seemd to be the problem, I renamed my table and java variables just in case and it solved my problem! Thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 1):

At the first sight-

`desc` is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) you have to enclose it in backticks ``

```
NSERT INTO tasks (category,completion_dtm,`desc`,duedate,notification_duedate,notification_one,notification_two,priority,reminder_one,reminder_two,title,timestamp) VALUES('None','3999-01-01 00:00:00','(null)',('1000-01-01 00:00:00'),'(null)','(null)','(null)',2,('1000-01-01 00:00:00'),('1000-01-01 00:00:00'),'Task 3',('1000-01-01 00:00:00')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id)
```

If you post the exact SQL error message, we can provide the more close answer.

Comment: Melvin Protacio let me know of this conflict so I resolved it quickly. But tanks for your post!

Answer (score 1):

You have column names matching with mysql keywords use backticks with your column names

Comment: Yes, Melvin Protacio kindly let me know it was conflicting. :-) Thanks for your reply anyway!